# OCaml function typing issue

Tags: function, functional-programming, ocaml, caml

I'm trying to write a Caml function and I'm having a few troubles with the typing. The function is :

```
let new_game size count gens =
  let rec continueGame board  = function
     0 -> ()
    |n -> drawBoard board size;
          continueGame (nextGeneration board) (n-1)

 in
 continueGame (seedLife (matrix 0 size) count)  (gens) ;;
```

Here are the types of other functions :

```
val drawBoard : int list list -> int -> unit = <fun>
val seedLife : int list list -> int -> int -> int list list = <fun>
val nextGeneration : int list list -> int list list = <fun>
val matrix : 'a -> int -> 'a list list = <fun>
```

When trying to evaluate `new_Game` I have the following error :

```
  continueGame (seedLife (matrix 0 size) count)  (gens);;
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 Error: This expression has type int -> int list list
        but is here used with type int list list
```

Why is this error occuring and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seedLife takes 3 arguments, but it's only passed 2.